# How to export python variable as javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a python variable in jupyter notebook

```
allFolders = {'1': { '2': {'3': { 'A' : {}, 'B' : {}, 'C': {}}}}}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to export this variable as a javascript file? What I currently have is:

```
file = open('allFolders.js','w')
file.write(allFolders)
file.close
```

Which does create a javascript file. However, does my python variable 'allFolders' need to be converted to JSON before this to be valid? My end goal is to import my 'allFolders.js' file into a 'directory.js' file so that 'directory.js' may use the contents of 'allFolders.js' as a const.

```
const {allFolders} = require('./allFolders.js');
```

But this doesn't seem to work. What steps am I missing here? I am very new to Javascript/JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write a `dict` object to the file. Try this

```
import json

file = open('allFolders.js', 'w')
file.write(json.dumps([allFolders]))
file.close
```

Passing **allFolders** `dict` as a `list` encloses it in square brackets essentially making it an **JSON** object.

Comment: If I do this, does 'allFolders.js' count as a JSON file? Or is it still Javascript at this point? (Thank you for your help!)

Comment: `open('allFolders.json', 'w')` and you can import using `require('./allFolders.json');`.

Comment: This is probably grounds to open a different question, but I received the error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined' and doing some research this is because require() does not exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript. Is there a different way to import my allFolders.json file to bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `all-folders` variable is a nested dictionary, why not export it as a `.json` instead of a `.js` file?

If you won't have any additional functionality like functions or additional variables inside your `Allfolders.js` file and only hold the dictionary object, Then it's better if you export it as a `.json` file and add/import the dictionary object/json value to a variable inside `directory.js` file

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your insight. I'm very new to this, but showing me the path of least resistance is so appreciated